Force closing parenthesis to new line for multiline condition
I understand, that setting the option AlignAfterOpenBracket to BlockIndent will put 'the closing parenthesis' on a new line for function calls, where the collection of arguments does not fit in one line.
What I want, however, is the same for conditions.
Example:
if (sufficientlyLongConditionToWarrantMultilining //Comment explaining the condition
  && shortConditionB
  && shortConditionC
) 
  operation();

My current configuration file makes of this:
if (sufficientlyLongConditionToWarrantMultilining //Comment explaining the condition
  && shortConditionB && shortConditionC) 
  operation();

Obviously, this is suboptimal, because the visual cue that the operation is, in fact, not part of the condition is almost lost.
I've looked through the documentation for a while, but, aside from BlockIndent, which only works for functions, couldn't find anything.
New lining every condition separately is a bonus, but not strictly necessary.
This is the file I've got so far (extracted from a QtCreator example FWIW):
---
Language:        Cpp
AccessModifierOffset: 0
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
AlignArrayOfStructures: Right
AlignConsecutiveAssignments:
  Enabled:         true
  AcrossEmptyLines: true
  AcrossComments:  true
  AlignCompound:   true
  PadOperators:    true
AlignConsecutiveBitFields:
  Enabled:         true
  AcrossEmptyLines: true
  AcrossComments:  true
  AlignCompound:   true
  PadOperators:    true
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: true
  AcrossComments:  true
  AlignCompound:   true
  PadOperators:    true
AlignConsecutiveMacros:
  Enabled:         true
  AcrossEmptyLines: true
  AcrossComments:  true
  AlignCompound:   true
  PadOperators:    true
AlignConsecutiveShortCaseStatements:
  Enabled:         true
  AcrossEmptyLines: true
  AcrossComments:  true
  AlignCaseColons: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands:   AlignAfterOperator
AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind:            Always
  OverEmptyLines:  1
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
AttributeMacros:
  - __capability
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  true
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      true
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile:     false
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakAfterAttributes: Never
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakArrays:     true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: Allowed
BreakBeforeInlineASMColon: OnlyMultiline
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
BreakInheritanceList: AfterComma
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     200
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Never
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: Always
FixNamespaceComments: false
ForEachMacros:
  - forever
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IfMacros:
  - KJ_IF_MAYBE
IncludeBlocks:   Regroup
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^<Q.*'
  - Priority:        200
  - SortPriority:    200
  - CaseSensitive:   true
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentAccessModifiers: false
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentExternBlock: Indent
IndentGotoLabels: false
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentRequiresClause: false
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
InsertBraces:    false
InsertNewlineAtEOF: true
InsertTrailingCommas: None
IntegerLiteralSeparator:
  Binary:          -1
  BinaryMinDigits: 0
  Decimal:         -1
  DecimalMinDigits: 0
  Hex:             -1
  HexMinDigits:    0
JavaScriptQuotes: Double
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtEOF: false
LambdaBodyIndentation: Signature
LineEnding:      LF
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2
NamespaceIndentation: None
PPIndentWidth:   0
PackConstructorInitializers: BinPack
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 150
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 300
PenaltyBreakComment: 500
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 400
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 600
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 50
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 0
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 300
PointerAlignment: Right
QualifierAlignment: Left
ReferenceAlignment: Pointer
ReflowComments:  true
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
RemoveParentheses: Leave
RemoveSemicolon: false
RequiresClausePosition: WithPreceding
RequiresExpressionIndentation: OuterScope
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Always
ShortNamespaceLines: 1
SortIncludes:    CaseSensitive
SortJavaStaticImport: Before
SortUsingDeclarations: Lexicographic
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeJsonColon: false
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 5
SpacesInAngles:  Never
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum:         1
  Maximum:         1
SpacesInParens:  Never
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        c++03
StatementAttributeLikeMacros:
  - Q_EMIT
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
  - Q_CLASSINFO
  - Q_ENUM
  - Q_ENUM_NS
  - Q_FLAG
  - Q_FLAG_NS
  - Q_GADGET
  - Q_GADGET_EXPORT
  - Q_INTERFACES
  - Q_MOC_INCLUDE
  - Q_NAMESPACE
  - Q_NAMESPACE_EXPORT
  - Q_OBJECT
  - Q_PROPERTY
  - Q_REVISION
  - Q_DISABLE_COPY
  - Q_SET_OBJECT_NAME
  - QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
  - QT_END_NAMESPACE
  - QML_ADDED_IN_MINOR_VERSION
  - QML_ANONYMOUS
  - QML_ATTACHED
  - QML_DECLARE_TYPE
  - QML_DECLARE_TYPEINFO
  - QML_ELEMENT
  - QML_EXTENDED
  - QML_EXTENDED_NAMESPACE
  - QML_EXTRA_VERSION
  - QML_FOREIGN
  - QML_FOREIGN_NAMESPACE
  - QML_IMPLEMENTS_INTERFACES
  - QML_INTERFACE
  - QML_NAMED_ELEMENT
  - QML_REMOVED_IN_MINOR_VERSION
  - QML_SINGLETON
  - QML_UNAVAILABLE
  - QML_UNCREATABLE
  - QML_VALUE_TYPE
TabWidth:        4
UseTab:          Always
VerilogBreakBetweenInstancePorts: false
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
  - CF_SWIFT_NAME
  - NS_SWIFT_NAME
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - STRINGIZE

Installed/bundled clang-format version is 17.0.01.
Thank you.
